# Rails validation messages for has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I'm having trouble accessing validation messages for a related model when saving. The setup is that a "Record" can link to many other records via a "RecordRelation" which has a label stating what that relation is, e.g. that a record "refers_to" or "replaces" another:

```
class Record < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :record_associations
  has_many :linked_records, through: :record_associations
  has_many :references, foreign_key: :linked_record_id, class_name: 'Record'
  has_many :linking_records, through: :references, source: :record
  ...
end

class RecordAssociation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :record
  belongs_to :linked_record, :class_name => 'Record'

  validates :label, presence: true
  ...
end
```

Creating the record in the controller looks like this:

```
def create
    # Record associations must be added separately due to the through model, and so are extracted first for separate
    # processing once the record has been created.
    associations = record_params.extract! :record_associations
    @record = Record.new(record_params.except :record_associations)
    @record.add_associations(associations)
    if @record.save
      render json: @record, status: :created
    else
      render json: @record.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end

  end
```

And in the model:

```
 def add_associations(associations)
    return if associations.empty? or associations.nil?
    associations[:record_associations].each do |assoc|
      new_association = RecordAssociation.new(
          record: self,
          linked_record: Record.find(assoc[:linked_record_id]),
          label: assoc[:label],
       )
      record_associations << new_association
    end
  end
```

The only problem with this is if the created association is somehow incorrect. Rather than seeing the actual reason, the error I get back is a validation for the Record, i.e.

```
{"record_associations":["is invalid"]}
```

Can anyone suggest a means that I might get record_association's validation back? This would be useful information for a user.

Comment: Can you please add your view file containing  this form here?

Comment: No, as there isn't one. This is an API application and so there's just JSON being passed back and forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example, I would rather go with `nested_attributes`. Then you should easily get access to associated record errors. An additional benefit of using it is removing custom logic you have written for such behavior.

For more information check documentation - https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at that.

Comment: Indeed, by passing the data through as record_associations_attributes I was able to remove my custom logic and all the tests still pass, so that seems to do the trick nicely - thanks.